# Оптимизация программы, которая находит все простые делители натурального числа N

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Что можно оптимизировать в данной программе, находящей все простые делители натурального числа `N`?

```
import math
def pr(r,n):
    if n % r == 0:
        m = int(math.sqrt(r))
        g = 2
        while g <= m:
            if r % g == 0:
                return
            g += 1
        print(r, end=' ')
        return
    else:
        return
n = int(input())
pr(2, n)
for i in range(3, n + 1, 2):
    pr(i, n)
```

Comment: @sentique это наверно тоже стоит указать в вопросе. Вдобавок, хорошо бы привести шаги, которые вы предприняли, для того, чтобы оптимизировать эту программу. И это не программа, это - код программы.

Comment: боюсь что ответ - всё. Тут сам алгоритм совсем не оптимален.

Comment: Какова цель оптимизации? Скорость выполнения? Красота и (или) краткость кода? Что-то еще?

Comment: Если вас интересует скорость, а также современные алгоритмы нахождения простых чисел (от решета Эратосфена до алгоритма Аткина и `Wheel Factorization`) то очень рекомендую посмотреть [вот этот шикарный ответ в английской версии SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068548/5741205)

Comment: @MaxU если о скорости говорить, то стоит обратить внимание на комментарий, упоминающий pyprimesieve.

Comment: @jfs, да, действительно! Судя по комментариям автора, `pyprimesieve`  быстрее самого быстрого из протестированных в ответе методов примерно в 5 раз

Comment: А зачем делить на все числа подряд? Можно только на нечетные, а еще лучше только на простые, но для их хранения надо очень много памяти.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pr(r, n=2):
    while n <= r:
        if r % n:
            n += 1
        else:
            r //= n
            yield n

print(set(pr(110)))
```